# Programmatically merging HSQLDB databases

Tags: java, database, merge, hsqldb

I'm working on a small game editor in java that gives the user the possibility to insert/edit/delete data in a HSQL database by using my UI. The problem I'm facing is, that i want to give the possibilty to work on such a game project on different machines and afterwards merge the databases programmatically.

The other thing I want to offer is moding, so people shall be able to create mods and use a specific game as their "base version" for it. It should also be possible to activite multiple mods at the same time, at least if they don't modify the same rows in the databases. In that case they would just be incompatible.

The database is fully offline, meaning I don't provide any server or something like this. The database contains about 30 tables, including NPCs, items, terrain (...) and links between all of them.

I allready saw some plugins for HSQLDB: C-JDBC, HA-JDBC and SymmetricDS. They are meant to perform clustering, but I'm not even sure if that's exactly the thing I need and also I wasn't able to figure out if they can do the job automatically from my code, in order to don't let the end user work with any 3rd party UI to merge it himself.

I also thought of just saving "changesets" maybe in XML structure, but that would mean that I'd have to implement the whole merging on my own and I would like to use existing solutions better than doing it all on my own.

Comment: I highly doubt that any database contains merge functionality that is built specifically to be able to do what your application needs. Of course you need to build the merge logic yourself; its business logic specific to YOUR application. I'd probably add a simple webservice connection to be able to make one instance adopt data from another; an import/export using JSON as the data format might be an easy alternative that requires no connection at all.

Answer (score 0):

The programs you mention: C-JDBC, HA-JDBC are not for this usage. They keep two servers running HSQLDB in sync in real time. SymmerticDS might have the capability that you want. There are other programs for database diff and merge that work fine with HSQLDB. Do a search. One example is here: http://flywaydb.org/

But what you really need to do is design your database so that it can store different versions (mods) of any game and of any mod. Look at how CVS works with dotted versions. You can implement the same kind of thing so a modified database does contain all the original rows of data of the base game without any change, but adds new rows for the new version or mod.

Merging such a database with a previous version is trivial, as you are just adding rows to the original that do not exit.

Comment: Thanks that helped a bit. But then I'm still facing the problem that existing rows can also be edited or deleted by mods. Would it be an appropriate way to use some kind of XML or JSON to just save "changesets"?

Comment: I added a link to software to do this. But if you implement a version based database, then existing rows are never deleted or modified.